# Neo4j Cypher return most consecutive "passes"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to return from a graph database the students with the most consecutive passes to a series of exams.

Below is my current code but not sure where I can take it from its current state to solve my issue.

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[r:TAKEN]->(e:Exam)
RETURN s.name, e.date,
  CASE 
    WHEN r.score >= e.pass_mark THEN 1
  END as pass
ORDER BY e.date
```

I would like a basic table which would show the student along with there most consecutive passes in a row.

For example:

```
| student   | pass/fail |
| joe       | pass      |
| matt      | pass      |
| joe       | fail      |
| matt      | pass      |    
| joe       | pass      |
| matt      | pass      |
| joe       | pass      |
| matt      | fail      |
```

And I would like the result from my query to display each student and their highest pass streak in a row.

```
| student  | passes in a row |
| joe      | 2               |
| matt     | 3               |
```

I have been playing around with `CASE` but haven't been able to come up with a good solution, currently, it will just list all the students for each exam and have a 1 if they have passed it.

Comment: Let me understand your question: your sample query is returning the first sample output of your question, right? Also, you need a query that returns the second sample output (student, passes in a row), right?

Comment: Also, Its a good idea provide a [console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with plain Cypher, but I don't think it's very practical - you essentially need to write a program with [`reduce`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce).

Basically, the "split" works as follows: initialize an empty accumulator list and calculate streaks by iterating through the list of passes/fails, check whether the current element is the same as the previous one. For example `['pass', 'pass']` keeps the streak, `['pass', 'fail']` breaks it. If it *breaks* (like at the start of the list), append a new element to the accumulator. If it *keeps*, append a new element to the last element of the accumulator, e.g. with a new `'fail'`, `[['pass', 'pass'], ['fail']]` becomes `[['pass', 'pass'], ['fail', 'fail]]`.

```
UNWIND
  [
    ['joe',  'pass'],
    ['matt', 'pass'],
    ['joe',  'fail'],
    ['matt', 'pass'],
    ['joe',  'pass'],
    ['matt', 'pass'],
    ['joe',  'pass'],
    ['matt', 'fail']
  ] AS row
WITH row[0] AS s, row[1] AS passed
WITH s, collect(passed) AS p
WITH s, reduce(acc = [], i IN range(0, size(p) - 1) | 
    CASE p[i] = p[i-1]
      WHEN true THEN [j IN range(0, size(acc) - 1) |
          CASE j = size(acc) - 1
            WHEN true THEN acc[j] + [p[i]]
            ELSE acc[j]
          END
        ]
      ELSE acc + [[p[i]]]
    END
  ) AS streaks // (1)
UNWIND streaks AS streak
WITH s, streak
WHERE streak[0] <> 'fail'
RETURN s, max(size(streak)) AS consecutivePasses // (2)
```

In step (1), this calculates streaks such as:

```
╒══════╤═════════════════════════════════╕
│"s"   │"streaks"                        │
╞══════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│"matt"│[["pass","pass","pass"],["fail"]]│
├──────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│"joe" │[["fail"],["pass","pass"]]       │
└──────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

And in (2), it gives:

```
╒══════╤═══════════════════╕
│"s"   │"consecutivePasses"│
╞══════╪═══════════════════╡
│"matt"│3                  │
├──────┼───────────────────┤
│"joe" │2                  │
└──────┴───────────────────┘
```

Of course, in this particular case it's not necessary to do the splitting: simply counting would be enough. But in 99% of practical situations, APOC is the way to go, so I did not bother optimising this solution.

Comment: Nice, I was curious about what a pure cypher solution would look like!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, and as far as I know can't be done with just Cypher, but there is a procedure in [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) that can help.

`apoc.coll.split()` takes a collection and a value to split around, and will yield records for each resulting sub-collection. Basically, we collect the ordered results per student, split around failures to get collections of consecutive passes, then get the max consecutive passes from the sizes of those collections:

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[r:TAKEN]->(e:Exam)
WITH s, r.score >= e.pass_mark as passed
ORDER BY e.date
WITH s, collect(passed) as resultsColl
CALL apoc.coll.split(resultsColl, false) YIELD value
WITH s, max(size(value)) as consecutivePasses
RETURN s.name as student, consecutivePasses
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue, I am unfamiliar with APOC so will make sure to read up on it.

Comment: You can do it in plain Cypher, you just wouldn't want to -- see my answer.