# Neo4j List Consecutive

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently working with a football match data set and trying to get Cypher to return the teams with the most consecutive wins.

At the moment I have a collect statement which creates a list i.e. `[0,1,1,0,1,1,1]` where `'0'` represents a loss and `'1'` represents a win. I am trying to return the team with the most consecutive wins.

Here is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
MATCH(t1:TEAM)-[p:PLAYS]->(t2:TEAM)
WITH [t1,t2] AS teams, p AS matches
ORDER BY matches.time ASC
UNWIND teams AS team
WITH team.name AS teamName, collect(case when ((team = startnode(matches)) AND (matches.score1 > matches.score2)) OR ((team = endnode(matches)) AND (matches.score2 > matches.score1)) then +1 else 0 end) AS consecutive_wins
RETURN teamName, consecutive_wins
```

This returns a list for each team showing their win / lose record in the form explained above (i.e. `[0,1,0,1,1,0]`)

Any guidance or help in regards to calculating consecutive wins would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671977/92359).

The key is using `apoc.coll.split()` from APOC Procedures, splitting on `0`, which will yield a row per winning streak (list of consecutive 1's) as `value`. The size of each of the lists is the number of consecutive wins for that streak, so just get the max size:

```
// your query above
CALL apoc.coll.split(consecutive_wins, 0) YIELD value
WITH teamName, max(size(value)) as consecutiveWins
ORDER BY consecutiveWins DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN teamName, consecutiveWins
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case does not actually require the detection of the most consecutive 1s (and it also does not need to use `UNWIND`).

The following query uses `REDUCE` to directly calculate the maximum number of consecutive wins for each team (`consW` keeps track of the current number of consecutive wins, and `maxW` is the maximum number of consecutive wins found thus far):

```
MATCH (team:TEAM)-[p:PLAYS]-(:TEAM)
WITH team, p
ORDER BY p.time ASC
WITH team,
  REDUCE(s = {consW: 0, maxW: 0}, m IN COLLECT(p) |
    CASE WHEN (team = startnode(m) AND (m.score1 > m.score2)) OR (team = endnode(m) AND (m.score2 > m.score1))
      THEN {consW: s.consW+1, maxW: CASE WHEN s.consW+1 > s.maxW THEN s.consW+1 ELSE s.maxW END}
      ELSE s
    END).maxW AS most_consecutive_wins
RETURN team.name AS teamName, most_consecutive_wins;
```