# List the most consecutive wins in cypher

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the most consecutive wins for a team. Firstly I have specified the win and lost results for every team but I have no idea how to get the most consecutive wins for the team

```
MATCH (a:TeamFootbal )-[r]->(m:Games)<-[r2]-(op:TeamFootbal)
with a.name as teamnames,
case when r.scores > r2.scores then 1 else 0 end as result
return teamnames, result
order by teamnames
```

The output will be like this

```
Team Name                     Result
A                             1
A                             1
A                             1
A                             0
A                             1
B                             1
B                             1
B                             1
B                             1
B                             0
C                             1
C                             0
C                             1
C                             1
C                             0
D                             0
D                             1
D                             0
D                             0
D                             1
E                             1
E                             1
E                             1
E                             1
E                             0
```

I want to get

```
B        4
E        4
```

without using the apoc procedure

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671393/neo4j-cypher-return-most-consecutive-passes/47671977. The question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791386/neo4j-list-consecutive is also related - both have two answers, one using APOC and another using plain Cypher (and the `reduce` function).

Comment: By the way, how do you make sure results are ordered according to the date of the game?

Comment: I've tried them, but the result wasn't correct

Comment: Gabor, I have ordered the result based on the team names.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps determine _consecutive_ wins.

Comment: It is not problem for me I will order the result based on the date but I want a way to count the most consecutive wins for every team and return the top one

Comment: As Gabor pointed out, you need some kind of timestamp or date property on your :Games nodes in order to order by date otherwise this isn't possible. Ordering by team name is useless here.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671393/neo4j-cypher-return-most-consecutive-passes/47671977) to a similar question:

```
MATCH (a:TeamFootbal)-[r]->(m:Games)<-[r2]-(op:TeamFootbal)
WITH
  a.name AS teamname,
  CASE WHEN r.scores > r2.scores THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
ORDER BY m.date ASC // (*)
WITH teamname AS s, collect([teamname, result]) AS p
WITH s, reduce(acc = [], i IN range(0, size(p) - 1) | 
    CASE p[i] = p[i-1]
      WHEN true THEN [j IN range(0, size(acc) - 1) |
          CASE j = size(acc) - 1
            WHEN true THEN acc[j] + [p[i]]
            ELSE acc[j]
          END
        ]
      ELSE acc + [[p[i]]]
    END
  ) AS streaks
UNWIND streaks AS streak
WITH s, streak
WHERE streak[0] <> 0
RETURN s, max(size(streak)) AS consecutivePasses
```

Note that ordering should be inserted at `(*)`

Comment: I have tested multiple times but it dose not give the accurate result

Comment: Please give me some test data so I can debug this.

Comment: I have edited the question and show you some sample of data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick to search the max number of following `1` in a list :

```
WITH [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] AS results
RETURN 
  reduce(
    // current value, highest value so far
    x=[0,0],
    i IN results |
      CASE 
        WHEN i=0 THEN [0 , x[1]]
        WHEN (x[0]+i) > x[1]  THEN [x[0] +1 , x[0]+1]
        ELSE [x[0] +1 , x[1]]
    END
  )
```