# Finding the consecutive win in Cypher query language

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: Arsenal club record ordered by time]

from fig we can see that Arsenal have won three match consecutively but I could not write the query.

Comment: You can reference [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671393/neo4j-cypher-return-most-consecutive-passes?rq=1) for how to get the number of max consecutive wins. However you'll need to alter your query so you can adequately determine (based on home/away team and score) if the club in question won or lost first.

Comment: Didn't Arsenal win 4 times in a row? I assume that the first `score` array element is the score for the home team, correct?

Comment: yeah you're correct Arsenal won 4 times in a row and the score array first element hold the home team score.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that should return the maximum number of consecutive wins for Arsenal:

```
MATCH (a:Club {name:'Arsenal FC'})-[r:played_with]-(:Club)
WITH ((CASE a.name WHEN r.home THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) * (TOINT(r.score[0]) - TOINT(r.score[1]))) > 0 AS win, r
ORDER BY TOINT(r.time)
RETURN REDUCE(s = {max: 0, curr: 0}, w IN COLLECT(win) |
  CASE WHEN w
    THEN {
      max: CASE WHEN s.max < s.curr + 1 THEN s.curr + 1 ELSE s.max END,
      curr: s.curr + 1}
    ELSE {max: s.max, curr: 0}
  END
  ).max AS result;
```

The `WITH` clause sets the `win` variable to `true` iff Arsenal won a particular game. Notice that the `ORDER BY` clause converts the `time` property to an integer, because the ordering of numeric *strings* does not work properly if the strings could be of different lengths (I am being a bit picky here, admittedly).  The `REDUCE` function is used to calculate the maximum number of consecutive wins.

======

Finally, here are some suggestions for some improvements to your data model. For example:

- It looks like your `played_with` relationship always points from the home team to the away team. If so, you can get rid of the redundant `home` and `away` properties, and you can also rename the relationship type to `HOSTED` to make the direction of the relationship more clear.
- The scores and time should be stored as integers, not strings. That would make your queries more efficient, and easier to write and understand.
- You could also consider splitting the `scores` property into two scalar properties, say `homeScore` and `awayScore`, which would make your code more clear. There seems to be no advantage to storing the scores in an array.

If you made all the above suggested changes, then you would just need to change the beginning of the above query to this:

```
MATCH (a:Club {name:'Arsenal FC'})-[r:HOSTED]-(:Club)
WITH ((CASE a WHEN STARTNODE(r) THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) * (r.homeScore - r.awayScore)) > 0 AS win, r
ORDER BY r.time
...
```